# VBA userform and module is getting attached to every Excel sheet I open

Tags: vba, excel

I added a VBA Form `userform` and a Module `Module1` in a Excel by opening the Microsoft VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) from the Excel.

Now, whenever I open any other Excel, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> takes me to the VBA editor and shows up that `userform` and the `Module1`.

The `userform` and `Module1` is basically getting tied to every Excel sheet I open?
What am I doing wrong?
How do I make sure my form is attached to the particular Excel sheet only and not others?

Comment: Does this hold true if you close all excel documents and open a new, empty one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, every userform/module is saved in one Excel file/project. But because there is only one VBA editor for all opened workbooks, you see the VBA codes of all open workbooks in one VBA editor.

Have a look into the *[Project Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264120.aspx)* of your VBA editor: Here you see the VBA codes (and userforms and modules) of all worksheets that are open at that time. And you can see which module/userform belongs to which Excel file/project.